# Is their a way to keep individual variables to themselves without adding them with each other c#

Tags: c#

Is their a way to add each variable by colum instead of individually adding each one?
Like if I wanted to multiply a row the code won't just take every variable and multiply it. I want the code to keep them in the same place and print it to the screen in the same format.

```
Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y + " " + z);
Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b + " " + c);
Console.WriteLine(ab + " " + bb + " " + cb);
```

Comment: What column? There's nothing here that has columns like a DataTable. What do you mean by add? You're just concatenating strings. Can you show some more information such as what values these variables hold and what your expected output is? The question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, im not very sure the best way to word the question

Comment: Keep what in the same place as what?

Comment: The problem is that you don't even have columns, you just print elements in console with spaces between them to *simulate* a column.

Comment: Didn't get your question

Comment: @hallkids1 your question is very unclear. Try to rephrase it and elaborate more. Also show some more code so we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @hallkids1 If you simply mean you want all values to be left/right aligned at the same X-Coordinate of the console you should go with @
R2dical's answer. If not - provide some example output of what you want. See [mcve] for details.

Comment: What do you mean by "like if I wanted to multiply a row the code won't just take every variable and multiply it"? The rest of your questions sounds like you're asking about display but this sounds like you want to apply operations to groups of numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

`Console.WriteLine("{0,10}{1,10}{2,10}", x, y, z);`

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I dont really understand

Comment: Despite the anonymous downvote, I think you are the only one who understood the question and answered it correctly.

Comment: This will format the output into columns, the first number inside the curly brackets is the index and the second is the alignment and the sign of the second number indicates if the string should be left or right aligned.

Comment: As showed in my answer, I'd suggest using the 'new' way: Console.WriteLine($"{x,10}{y,10}{z,10}"); It is shorter and more readable.

Comment: @hallkids1 Did you even read the MSDN page he linked?

Comment: @MaartenvanStam but only works with C# 6.0

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer True, it is a C# 6 and up feature. A beautiful one that helps you clean up your code to make it a lot more readable if you do have that version or up..

Comment: @MaartenvanStam Thanks, yeah the question was quite vague :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine($"{x}\t{y}\t{z}");
Console.WriteLine($"{a}\t{b}\t{c}");
Console.WriteLine($"{ab}\t{bb}\t{cb}");
```

Note: This format is supported as from C# 6 and up.

Comment: You can also add the c# version that supports this syntax..

Comment: True, I expected the OP to be on the latest version as he didn't mention his version but you are right. Added the version 'disclaimer'.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;

    ConsoleWriteColumn(x,y,z);

    Console.WriteLine("Multiplied by 2:");

    ConsoleWriteColumn((x*2),(y*2),(z*2));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ConsoleWriteColumn(int value1, int value2, int value3)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{value1,5}{value2,5}{value3,5}");
}
```